# Python: Get Windows username of user viewing page?

Tags: python, windows-authentication, django-authentication

Is there a way in Python/Django to get the username of the currently logged-in Windows user, from an app that is not running locally?

UPDATE: sorry, to clarify, by this I mean the *Windows username of the user viewing the web page*, not the user running the server.

I've tried both:

```
 current_user = os.environ.get("USERNAME")
 current_user_getpass = getpass.getuser()
```

But I think they're returning the name of the user running the server.

Thanks!

FURTHER UPDATE: I don't care greatly about security. It really doesn't matter if users spoof a username. What does matter is convenience. I just need a way to get the username without users having to fiddle around with passwords or install client-side software. Any ideas?

Comment: The user the server is running under has **nothing** to do with the `AUTHORIZATION` header in the HTML request.  Which username do you want?

Comment: Sorry - I'm confused, clearly. I want the login name of the *user looking at the web page*, not the user running the server.

Comment: Please **update** your question to be clear.  Don't comment on your question.  Please **update** it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Three ways, none of which work.

1. Use the [Ident (AUTH) protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ident). It's *technically* cross-platform.

   <s>...except there are exactly *zero* Ident servers for Windows that are able to return the real user name instead of a static string.</s>

   Edit: Apparently [**Retina Scan Identd**](http://sourceforge.net/projects/retinascan/) can do this. (Awesome.)
2. Require HTTP [`NTLM`](http://modntlm.sourceforge.net/) or [`Negotiate`](http://modauthkerb.sourceforge.net/) authentication. You get *more* than a mere username check,

   ...except NTLM is insecure, only Internet Exploder and Firefox support it, and they only use it inside the LAN (intranet) by default. `Negotiate` is able to use the more secure Kerberos, but it (obviously) requires Kerberos on both server and clients. If the Windows PCs are in a domain, good. If not...
3. If you *control all client machines*, you can use simple SSL client-certificate authentication. Works in all modern browsers.

   ...but every user needs their own certificate. Creating an internal-use CA and issuing certificates is simple; getting them installed and working in client machines - not so.

Comment: Great answer, thanks. I don't care a whole lot about security (it's a low-security app): I care about convenience for my users. When you say NTLM runs inside the LAN by default, what would I need to ask users to do to use it? (Background: I'm writing a web app that will function as part of an intranet, but I want to host it in the cloud if possible.) Many thanks again.

Comment: @AP257: For IE, add the app to "Intranet" or "Trusted" zone; for Firefox, configure `network.automatic-ntlm-auth.trusted-uris` (and if you choose Kerberos, `network.negotiate-auth.trusted-uris`). On a Active Directory domain, it could be done using Group Policy.